# SSO Implementation for Desktop and Web Application with Windows Credential

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, adfs, domaincontroller

I have a windows application and a web application. Both are having a different login screen. Is there a way to implement SSO with the help of windows credential so that user don't need to login again for accessing the applications.

Note : I am new to ADFS , Domain Controller and SSO so don't have much idea on how that works.

Any leads is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement SSO for your corporate/internal/on-premises application using Windows Active Directory and [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/windows-authentication-overview). A [Domain Controller](https://www.techtarget.com/searchwindowsserver/definition/domain-controller) stores the Windows Active Directory database. [ADFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/active-directory-federation-services) will help you extend your Identity and SSO capabilities trusting 3ra party Identity providers. E.g. [Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory/). With this you will be able to access applications in both networks with a single set of credentials.